# How to send file through Bluetooth using Intent

Tags: android

I want to send set of string via bluetooth. I googled for sending text via bluetooth using intent action, but I didn't get any proper answer. also I tried in developer.android.com, but I confused about there codings. How to transfer the file via bluetooth using intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can send text or a file via Bluetooth via an Intent unless you have a supporting app. Intents are for invoking/calling between applications/activites on the device. As there is no predefined Intent for such a thing you would need to write it yourself. For an idea of how to use Bluetooth on Android look at the [Bluetooth Chat](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html) sample program in the samples directory of the SDK.

Answer (score 5):

You can make an explicit call to ACTION_SEND using intents as shown below.

You can send a file to a paired device through obex in a couple of ways:

With the ACTION_SEND intent, that will popup a menu with the application that can handle the file type you want to send, from which the user will need to select bluetooth, and then the device.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("image/jpeg");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("/sdcard/file.jpg"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send Image"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
            type = "text/plain"
            `package` = "com.android.bluetooth"
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("some Uri string")
        }

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share File"))
```

Instead of having the user choose the Bluetooth application from the chooser list, we call the `setPackage("com.android.bluetooth")` or `` Intent.`package`="com.android.bluetooth `` (kotlin). This will let the user to only choose the destination device and the system will handle the transfer asynchronously